# SQL Server - Invalid characters in parameter names

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

I need to know what are the valid characters to use in a SQL parameter name.

Given something simple like `SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE testid = @[X]`, if X contains a hyphen, for instance, the statement will fail.  What are the valid characters for parameter names?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Search for "Identifiers" in your SQL Books online, and you should find:

**Rules for Regular Identifiers**

> The rules for the format of regular identifiers depend on the database
>   compatibility level. This level can be set by using sp_dbcmptlevel. 
>   When the compatibility level is 90, the following rules apply:
>
> The first character must be one of the following:
>
> - A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode    definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z,
>     from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
> - The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).
>
> Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special 
>   meaning in SQL Server. A regular identifier that starts with the at 
>   sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be  used
>   as the name of any other type of object. An identifier that  starts
>   with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure.  An
>   identifier that starts with double number signs (##) denotes a  global
>   temporary object. Although the number sign or double number  sign
>   characters can be used to begin the names of other types of objects, 
>   we do not recommend this practice.
>
> Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs
>   (@@).  To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use
>   names that  start with @@.
>
> Subsequent characters can include the following:
>
> - Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 3.2.
> - Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.
> - The at sign, dollar sign ($), number sign, or underscore.
>
> The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server 
>   reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words. 
>   Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.  Supplementary
>   characters are not allowed.

Search for "delimited identifiers" in your SQL Books online, and you should find:

> The body of the identifier can contain
>   any combination of characters in the
>   current code page, except the
>   delimiting characters themselves. For
>   example, delimited identifiers can
>   contain spaces, any characters valid
>   for regular identifiers, and any one
>   of the following characters.
>
> ```
> tilde (~)                hyphen (-)   
> exclamation point (!)    left brace ({)   
> percent (%)              right brace (})   
> caret (^)                apostrophe (')   
> ampersand (&)            period (.)   
> left parenthesis (()     backslash (\)   
> right parenthesis ())    accent grave (`)
> ```

Marc

Comment: Also dangerous: /+=;\r\n,<>[]*"# and NULL/string.empty, as well as @ as in @@sql_server_setting.

Answer (score 0):

Search Books Online for identifiers [SQL Server]. It has the rules that parameter names must follow. (this was the SQL Server 2008 search), other versions should be a similar search